# Finding the index of an element that satisfies a predicate in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a built-in/library function or method in Python that searches a list for a certain element that satisfies a predicate and returns the index. I'm looking for a built-in function because I feel that this should be in the Python libraries.

It is similar to, e.g. `[(10, 1), (20, 2), (30, 3)].index((30, 3))` that returns 2, but I want a custom comparison function, for example, I just want to match the first element of the tuple in the earlier example.

What I am looking is a function that essentially does this:

```
def custom_index(l, f):
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
         if f(e): return i
    return -1 # or something else to indicate not found
```

Usage:

```
custom_index([(10, 1), (20, 2), (30, 3)], lambda x: x[0]==30) -> returns 2
```

Comment: The answers to the possible dupe suggest that there is no such built-in/library function

Comment: @Leon The question you linked wants the item itself, yuku wants the item's index.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no standard library function that does this. FWIW, here's your function made into a one-liner: `def custom_index(l, f): return next((i for i, e in enumerate(l) if f(e)), -1)`

Answer (score 6):

There's not such a built-in function, but here's another possible version of the function you're looking for:

```
def custom_index(it, f, default=-1):
    return next((i for i, e in enumerate(it) if f(e)), default)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use Python index function with the help of list comprehension

```
l = [(10, 1), (20, 2), (30, 3)]
[t[0] for t in l].index(30)
```